# Exhaust plume length variation across different rocket types

Tags: rockets, flame

In rockets we see exhaust plume smaller and bigger. I know length has some relation with the fuel mixture ratio (not confident about it).

How to calculate, or at least understand, the variation in the wide variation in the apparent length of the exhaust plume of different rocket/engine combinations?

Comment: I guess we should call it an "exhaust plume" rather than a flame. Most of the combustion or reaction takes place within the engine or body (depending on type) and the heat generated is used to produce expansion in the nozzle to generate momentum.

Comment: If you only account for the clearly visible part ("flame"), it also depends on the type of fuel: hydrogen burns basically invisible (see: RS-68). Kerosene on the otherhand produces a fairly long "flame" (see: Merlin).

Comment: @uhoh, I am actually looking if there is some formula with which we can calculate the plume length for different propellants.

Comment: @Amar I'm confident there will not be a single formula that works across multiple propellants, engine types, sizes, flow-rates, nozzle expansion ratios, etc. There are so many factors that go into the *visibility* of a plume, most of which has to do with several different secondary processes that each produces a different spectrum of light. See for example [What is the cause of the blue light from LH2/LOX rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16821/12102) and also [How do rocket propellant combinations rank in terms of “brightness”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20601/12102)

Comment: @Amar also see the as-yet unanswered [What makes exhaust from aluminum-based SRB propellant so bright?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26194/12102) as well as [How bright is a rocket launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19290/12102). Then look at [Why do the exhaust flames from cryogenic stage engines appear to be separated from the nozzle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2017/12102)

Comment: @Amar do you ask about the length of VISIBLE plume? If yes - it depends on exhaust products. Hydrogen/oxygen exhaust (e.g Delta-4 rocket) is almost invisible, as vell as hydrazine/dinitrogen tetroxide (Proton rocket). It's because the exhaust consist of gases only. Kerosene engines (Falcon, Soyuz) produce a lot of soot particles, so we see prominent exhaust flame. Solid fuel propellants (Space Shuttle SRBs, etc.) produce even more solid particles in exhaust, so the exhaust doesn't dissipates for a long time.

Comment: @Heopps The length of the plume where the temperature is about 1000 deg C.